# python "hide" a big literal at the end of the source code/forward reference?

Tags: python-2.7

I have this source file set up to run tests if it is run as `__main__`.

```
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    import sys

    expected_output = '''
         (60-line literal that represents the correct output)'''

    [run the tests collecting output in a variable named output]

    [compare output to expected_output]
```

I would love to put that huge literal down at the bottom of the file, but I can't think of a way to create a forward reference to it.

Am I just basically out of luck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign the data before you can use it. The trick is to put the stuff you currently have in `if __name__==__main__` into a function at the top of the code. Then you can put all the good code in that function, add the big blob of ugliness and put a very simple `if` at the bottom. By the time `main()` is called, the variable as been assigned and you are good to go.

```
import sys # aren't saving anything by putting it in the `if`

def main():
    [run the tests collecting output in a variable named output]
    [compare output to expected_output]

expected_output = '''
    (60-line literal that represents the correct output)'''

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main()
```

@tdelaney Here is a slight embellishment on your suggestion.

```
def main(expected_output):
    [run the tests collecting output in a variable named output]
    [compare output to expected_output]


if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main(
'''
(60-line literal that represents the correct output)
'''
)
```

Comment: Here is a slight embellishment on your suggestion.

def main():
    [run the tests collecting output in a variable named output]
    [compare output to expected_output]

expected_output = 

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main('''
    (60-line literal that represents the correct output)''')

Comment: yes, that works too. But if the goal is to put all the good stuff at the top so that people don't have to scroll through the ugliness to see the logic of the program, you've ended up putting the most important step in the "no go" zone.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the no-go zone. In terms of your comment the distracting material I am trying to move to the end is the long literal. This is maximized with the embellishment.

All of the testing material is after the if __name__ == '__main__'. I perceive that as easier to find, although I would not argue with someone saying that people tend to ignore that zone.

Once again, your suggestion was great.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, in python everything should be defined before you use it. I'd recommend to put the literal into a different file.

If you must, technically, you can put your literal into the same file, at the very end of the code and then read it with introspection or just as a file.

```
with open(__file__) as f: expected_output = f.read().rsplit("'''")[-2]
```

though I find storing large literals in separate file(s) is easier to maintain and read.

Comment: Thanks. I had thought of that and wasn't willing to add the complication of an additional file.